# pyqtgraph Lock dock layout

Tags: python, dock, pyqtgraph

Is there a way to lock docks in pyqtgraph so that the user cannot move them around?

I'm using a small touchscreen to display a pyqtgraph application with multiple docks.  It is very easy for the user to accidentally move a dock.  When that happens the screen becomes unusable because of the size.  I would like to prevent the user from moving the docks.

However, the user must still be able to choose between docks (i.e. treat them like a tab widget).

Just to be clear, I want to prevent a dock from being detached and I want to prevent the dock from being drug to a new location.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to disable the ability to detach and drag docks by overriding the Dock class' methods.

Dragging a dock moves it to another location.  So I overrode all of the 'drag' event handlers with methods that do nothing (i.e. a no-op).

Double-clicking on a dock's label will cause the dock to detach.  So, I overrode the dock's label's double-click event handler with a no-op.

Replace Dock with MyDock in your code. UPDATE: I added code to override the drag methods for the DockArea too because I was still able to move DockAreas around.

Here is the code:

```
##
# This class is used to eliminate a standard Dock class' ability to detach and
# move (i.e. dragging this Dock will have no effect)
#
class MyDock(Dock):
    def __init__(self, name, area=None, size=(10, 10), widget=None, hideTitle=False, autoOrientation=True):

        # Initialize the baseclass
        #
        Dock.__init__(self, name, area, size, widget, hideTitle, autoOrientation)

        # Override the label's double click event.  Normally double clicking
        # the dock's label will cause it to detach into it's own window.
        #
        self.label.mouseDoubleClickEvent=self.noopEvent

    def dragEventEnter(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragMoveEvent(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragDropEvent(self, ev):
        pass

    def noopEvent(self,ev):
        pass

class MyDockArea(DockArea):
    def dragEventEnter(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragMoveEvent(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, ev):
        pass

    def dragDropEvent(self, ev):
        pas
```